# How can I invoke a script using cron daemon

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I need to invoke my shell script every two days, I read about cron daemon that it can help me invoking scripts periodically, so can you give an example how can I make my script able to be invoked by cron daemon.

Comment: Don't forget that cron's environment is not your environment. Don't rely on your $PATH for calling external commands. Beware of other environment variables your program (or invoked programs) uses. You can your source your shell's rc files if you need your particular environment.

Answer (score 2):

Invoke `crontab -e` to bring up the cron editor

The format for crontab is:  MIN HOUR DAY MONTH DAYOFWEEK  COMMAND

Therefore to make a script run every 2 days, you'll want:

```
0 0 */2 * * /path/to/command
```

Once you're done, type `:x` to save and quit.  You can then run `crontab -l` (that's an ell) to make sure it took hold.

*Note: It's actually a bit ambiguous if your cron daemon will run that every two days on even days (2,4,6..) or odd days (1,3,5..) and it may switch these depending on how many days are in the current month.  If you want to unambigufy this, you can do this:

#### Run on Odd Days

```
0 0 1-31/2 * * /path/to/command
```

#### Run on Even Days

```
0 0 0-30/2 * * /path/to/command
```

Answer (score 1):

```
0 0 1-31/2 * * your_script
________^ NOT divined, but run every 2 days
```

the above will run once in two days at 00:00:00am

you can do `man 5 crontab` to get some helpful information

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to execute **exactly** every 48 hours with the classical cron, not even with more than one tab entry.

Every 2 days is an average of 0.5 times per day. However, "1-31/2" as posted by others, runs 0.509851 times per day on average, in other words: approx every 47h 4min over a timeframe of 400 years. (Because it will run on both the 31st of an odd month, and the 1st of the following month.)

Edit: "*/2" would run 179x/year, which is 0.49041, so that is not exact either.

Hooray for the Gregorian calendar.